# Is there a way that I can get the electricity units consumed during charging a phone

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am making an android app in android studio in java in which user can collect the data that how much electricity will be consumed and cost of electricity during charging a cell phonea.Plz help me I really want to know.
Thanks

Comment: I doubt you can do it through software. My experience is that chargers draw 5-10 Watts

Comment: How you will suggest me to achieve this.

Comment: You can't (probably)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's like watt meter app

Answer (score 0):

intentfilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                MainActivity.this.registerReceiver(broadcastreceiver, intentfilter);

            }
        });

}

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastreceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        
        batteryVol = (int)(intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, 0));
        volTextView.setText(batteryVol + " Mah");

    }
};
```